# Silverlight: Add a resource dictionary from another project

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a XAML resource dictionary in project A. How can I merge it into a resource dictionary in project B?

Comment: Are both projects in the same solution?

Comment: No, one of the projects is only accessible via a DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where Granite.Xaml is the library and ConvertersList.xaml has been marked as a resource.

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/Granite.Xaml;component/ConvertersList.xaml" />
```

Here is the contents of the resource dictionary. Note that I had to include the assembly name in the namespace declaration even though the converters are in the same project as the dictionary. If you fail to do this you will get a runtime exception.

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Granite.Xaml.Converters;assembly=Granite.Xaml"
    >

    <converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
    <converters:DebugBreakConverter x:Key="DebugBreakConverter" />
    <converters:DebugTraceConverter x:Key="DebugTraceConverter" />
    <converters:DictionaryConverter x:Key="DictionaryConverter" />
    <converters:MaxLengthToBoolTrueConverter x:Key="MaxLengthToBoolTrueConverter" />
    <converters:MinLengthToBoolTrueConverter x:Key="MinLengthToBoolTrueConverter" />
    <converters:NotBoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NotBoolToVisibilityConverter" />
    <converters:NotConverter x:Key="NotConverter" />
    <converters:NotNullToBooleanConverter x:Key="NotNullToBooleanConverter" />
    <converters:NotNullToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NotNullToVisibilityConverter" />
    <converters:NotZeroToBooleanConverter x:Key="NotZeroToBooleanConverter" />
    <converters:NotZeroToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NotZeroToVisibilityConverter" />
    <converters:NullToBooleanConverter x:Key="NullToBooleanConverter" />
    <converters:NullToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NullToVisibilityConverter" />
    <converters:StringToBooleanConverter x:Key="StringToBooleanConverter" />
    <converters:StringToLowerConverter x:Key="StringToLowerConverter" />
    <converters:StringToUpperConverter x:Key="StringToUpperConverter" />
    <converters:ZeroToBooleanConverter x:Key="ZeroToBooleanConverter" />
    <converters:ZeroToVisibilityConverter x:Key="ZeroToVisibilityConverter" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Namespace.From.Your.Dll;component/Style.xaml"/>      
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```